# Finding similarities between binary strings

Tags: puzzle, binary, programming

I have been tasked with this puzzle for my programming class, it's purely a puzzle and doesn't count towards any grades, but not being able to solve it is really bugging me!
We have been given two binary strings and have to find a pattern between the two:

First:  0011 1010 0001 0001 0111 1111

Second: 1001 0000 1111 0000 1000 0101

Both strings are 24 bits long, but the decimal conversions share no resemblance.
I have tried breaking them down and looking for patterns, is it possible the binary should be reverse, should it be 4 bit wide decimals, hex??

E.g. should each 4 bit block be converted to decimal?

0011   1010   0001   0001   0111   1111

3        10        1       1         7       15

Or should it be 12 bits wide?

001110100001   000101111111

929                      383

3A1                     17F

I am completely stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I think one possible interpretation of the problem is "Find the longest common substring." (i.e., a string of 0s and 1s that appears in both is one form of a common pattern.)

But the way this problem is presented here, it's not obvious that that is the correct interpretation.